# Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tbl1' for update in FROM clause(Delete query)

Tags: mysql

Trying to delete records with some conditions but MySQL throwing error:
  `Error Code: 1093`

```
delete from tbl1
where date(cast(traptime as datetime))< date_sub(current_date, interval 200  day) and 
id not in (select max(id) as id from tbl1 group by device_name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        select max(id) as id from tbl1 group by device_name
    ) AS c
)
and date(cast(traptime as datetime))< date_sub(current_date, interval 200  day)
```

Comment: Work Fine and thanks for super fast answer :)

Comment: @Code-Monk:- You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part. See answer here: 
[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: If the answer is in another question, just flag it as a duplicate, don't post a link-only answer.